# Bradley-Terry models in R with multiple batches of random effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, bradley-terry-model

I want to fit Bradley-Terry models in R looked into the `BradleyTerry2` package. However, as they write in [their vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BradleyTerry2/vignettes/BradleyTerry.pdf):

> (Note that a random intercept is the only random effect structure
> currently implemented in BradleyTerry2.)

In the CEMS example, there are student-specific variables x that influence which school (i vs j) wins for them:

$\text{logit}[pr(i\text{ beats }j\ |\ \text{person with covariate }x)] = \lambda_i - \lambda_j + (\beta_i - \beta_j) x$

Suppose we want to model parameters as random effects:

$\lambda_i \sim N(0, \sigma_\lambda)$

$\beta_i \sim N(0, \sigma_\beta)$

Is there a way to do this in R, e.g. by directly specifying design matrices with the 0,-1,1 or 0,-x,x entries ? I do not see how to do this in R using `lme4`, `BradleyTerry2`, `mgcv`, etc.

Thank you !